# Как привязать счетчик к текущей дате и времени?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть счетчик имитирующий подсчет выпущенных открыток, который стартует каждый раз при заходе на страницу с условных 200 000 000 штук. Как сделать так, чтобы при заходе на страницу счет привязывался к дате и времени и продолжался уже с большего числа, чем пользователь увидел впервые, чтобы не бросалось прям в глаза то, что его обманывают.

```js
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
var intercash;
 
    $(document).ready(function($){
            clearInterval(intercash);

            {
                intercash = setInterval(
                    function(){
                        cash = $("#cash").text().replace(/\s/g, '');
                        cash = parseInt(cash);
                        cash += 25+Math.round(Math.random()*15);
                        cash = cash.toString();
                        $("#cash").text(cash.substr(0,2)+" "+cash.substr(2,3)+" "+cash.substr(5,3));
                    },
                    1000
                );
            }

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="cash">200 000 000</span> открыток
```

Comment: Накрутка счётчика?) Ая-я-й

Comment: @Doofy нет, не то что вы подумали - никто ж не будет пересчет вести открыток каждую секунду, приблизительное значение задается алгоритмом. знаете как решить?

Comment: проверить нет ли сохраненного значения, если есть  - начать с него, если нет - поставить нормально и сохранить, плюс обновлять его каждые сколько-то там времени

Comment: Нужен алгоритм, который на любом компе будет генерить одинаковую последовательность, как функцию времени. Я бы взял одномерный шум Перлина.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот требуемая привязка к дате и времени на клиенте:

```js
var startValue = 0;  // Начальное значение.
var startTime = new Date(2016, 06, 05, 11, 30, 0).getTime();  // Начальная дата.
var inSec = 3;  // Число штук, добавляемых в секунду.

// Пересчитываем начальное значение.
value = startValue + Math.round(((new Date).getTime() - startTime) / 1000 * inSec);

function add() {
    value += inSec;
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = value;
}

setInterval(add, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="counter"></p>
```

Недостаток в том, что клиент может изменить время, перезагрузить страницу и увидеть обман. Более правильным решением будет хранить счётчик на сервере и присылать клиенту страницу с правильным начальным значением счётчика, который будет увеличиваться каждую секунду уже клиентским кодом.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужна функция от времени, которая

1. одинаково вычисляется на любом устройстве (`Math.random()` не годится);
2. растёт, не убывая, с заданной средней скоростью +N в сутки;
3. растёт неравномерно – то быстрее, то медленнее.

Мне сразу представляется график такой функции. Просто растущая линия это `f(x) = k * x`

[image: Y = kX]

Чтобы добавить неравномерности прибавим `sin(x)`:

[image: Y = kX + sin(X)]

Остаётся подобрать коэффициенты, чтобы синусоида никогда не шла вниз, период был равен суткам, стартовало с 200 млн.:

```js
dN = 200000; // прирост за период
dT = 86400; // секунд в период
sT = new Date(2016, 05, 01); // начало 1-го июня 2016
sN = 200000000; // число на начало

out = document.getElementById("out");

function getValue() {
  T = Math.floor(((new Date()).getTime() - sT) / 1000); // время в секундах с начала отсчёта
  return sN + Math.floor(T * dN/dT + dN * Math.sin( T*2*Math.PI/dT)/(4*Math.PI));
}

function showValue() {
  out.innerText = getValue();
}

showValue();
window.setInterval( showValue, 80);
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, ваш ответ очень подходит моей проблеме, но я не пойму одного, почему отсчет начинается с такого числа? Как сделать чтобы он начинался с 20 000 000 и шел делая +7700 каждую секунду?

Comment: @MidNightElf так  https://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/hme0gx89/

Comment: что значит 2e8? Если поменять его на, к примеру, 110000 то отсчет начинается не с этого, а с другого числа. Что если я хочу поменять его начальное значение?

Comment: `2e8` это "2" с восемью нулями. Ошибся, надо было `2e7 = 20 000 000`
Когда писал ответ, я посмотрел текущее время в формает Unix time - число миллисекунд с 1970 - и его использовал как точку отсчета.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var now = (new Date()).getTime() / 86400; //Количество дней прошедших с 1 января 1970
var cardsSent = now * 1000; //По тысяче в день
var div = document.getElementById('cash');
div.innerHTML = Math.round(cardsSent).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
```

```html
<div id="cash"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо, странно, что у вас код виден не в динамике, а при обновлении страницы только

Comment: В моём ответе только та часть кода, которая относится непосредственно к вопросу. Можно сначала вызвать мой код, он установит начальной значение, а потом вашим кодом его наращивать каждую секунду.